# Nodejs Caching Stateful Objects with Callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, fsm

My Express Nodejs application uses a State Machine, which stores its states on the domain objects that are initiated with the State Machine (i.e [Machina Behaviorial FSM](http://machina-js.org/)).

These domain objects have a timeout function on it which triggers a state transition on timeout.

I am currently holding these objects in a global variable in my Node run time.

What would be a good strategy to store these objects so that I still retain state if my node run-time restarts?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the durability guarantees required could determine whether in memory store or file based store is more appropriate to store your object states.

On each state change you could serialize the current data of your object and its state and persist it to an in memory cache or file based storage.  Then when your process starts up, part of the initialization could be to make a request to storage and create new objects and put them in the required states.